# Change System Navigation Bar Color in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, navbar

I am trying to change the System Navigation Bar Color in my app with below code.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,));
```

I am able to change it but when i navigate to other screen it changes back to its original color which is black and white color is not showing again unless i reload the app. How to fix it.

Comment: Are you doing this in main() function, right ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After flutter 3.1+ you can directly add navigation bar theme into your main themedata, but please check `useMaterial3 : true` property to use that theme

Comment: how can we change status bar icon color to black only...i changed it but after navigating to some screens it appears white again

Comment: you need to provide icon brightness dark or white. If you add navigation theme to your material app, it won't change until and unless you manually provide different style to your screen

Answer (score 0):

Initialize that code at start in home page or where your app starts

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
     systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
   ));
 }
```

this will apply it globally